# R multiplying cell wise without inefficient loops

Tags: r, loops

I have the following data set structure where each entry is the probability of that team score that many points (eg probability of team a score 1 point in game 1 is 0.1).

```
library(data.table)

x = data.table(matrix(c('game_1', 'team_a', 0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 'game_1', 'team_b', 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1,
                        'game_2', 'team_a', 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 'game_2', 'team_b', 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2), ncol=6, byrow=T))
names(x) = c('game_number', 'team', 'point_1', 'point_2', 'point_3', 'point_4')

x

#    game_number   team point_1 point_2 point_3 point_4
# 1:      game_1 team_a     0.1     0.2     0.6     0.1
# 2:      game_1 team_b     0.2     0.3     0.4     0.1
# 3:      game_2 team_a     0.2     0.1     0.5     0.2
# 4:      game_2 team_b     0.3     0.2     0.3     0.2
```

I want to know the probability of each team winning each game (and the probability of a draw in each game).  Is there a way to do this without a large, inefficient loop?

eg the probability of team a winning game 1:

`= 0.1*0.4 + 0.1*0.3 + 0.1*0.2 + 0.6*0.3 + 0.6*0.2 + 0.2*0.2`

Comment: Not following your example calculation of  "the probability of team a winning game 1" with the provided data set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a good function to do this, but here is how I would solve it. Note that I only use the probability data for this. Also, this script should work for any number of matches and any number of points.

```
library(data.table)
x = data.table(matrix(c('game_1', 'team_a', 0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 'game_1', 'team_b', 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1,
                        'game_2', 'team_a', 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 'game_2', 'team_b', 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2), ncol=6, byrow=T))
names(x) = c('game_number', 'team', 'point_1', 'point_2', 'point_3', 'point_4')

x[, point_1 := as.numeric(point_1)]
x[, point_2 := as.numeric(point_2)]
x[, point_3 := as.numeric(point_3)]
x[, point_4 := as.numeric(point_4)]

x2 <- x
x2[, c('game_number','team') := NULL]
```

So first, we have to calculate the cumulative probability

```
# Calculate the cumulative probability
y <- t(apply(x2,1,cumsum))
```

From there on, we want to multiply the cumulative probability with the corresponding score probabilities of the other team.

```
# Remove the 1 probability column in the end
y <- y[, -ncol(y)]

# Swap every odd with every subsequent even row
even <- seq(2, nrow(y), by=2)
sequence <- c(rbind(even,even-1))
y <- y[sequence,]

# Multiply the two vectors with each other
x2[, point_1 := NULL]
z <- x2 * y
```

Finally, we update x to contain a column `prob` that will contain the probability that the team will win that match.

```
# Find the probability of winning
x[, prob := rowSums(z)]
```

Comment: You can do all those `:=` assignments in one step. Have a look at the [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).